# Grafana v8 Table display double metric on cloudwatch

Tags: grafana

hello i found something on table panel when i use metric search on cloudwatch

i want only FunctionName but panel display FunctionName and metricname

panel A : SEARCH(' {AWS/Lambda, FunctionName}, MetricName="ProvisionedConcurrentExecutions" ', 'Sum', 300)

panel B : SEARCH(' {AWS/Lambda, FunctionName}, MetricName="ConcurrentExecutions" ', 'Sum', 300)

table panel show
[panel table show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3N5ZF.png)

Answer (score 0):

Define `Alias` properly - `{{FunctionName}}`.

Comment: i try to define alias  {{FunctionName}} , but it same